# Unable to access Google Play because of account verification problem

Tags: google-play-store, htc-desire

My dad has a HTC desire A8181 and he has a problem where he can't log on to google play.

It happened like this: 2 years ago my dad got a message that he had to log in to google play on a Google account but he forgot his password so he did nothing and just didn't log in. Now he wants to log back on to his play store and download an app so I installed another Google account and that worked. Now his phone gives a popup every time i try to install an app that says

> Verification required, you have to log on to your google account (translated from dutch)

The app does not install and it says that every time. How can my dad log in to his account to verify it and solve the problem? Or is there another solution to solve this and install apps?

Answer (score 1):

Because this account is the *primary* account on the device, Google Play tends to use it as the default. You can switch which account to use by opening the side drawer:

[image]

You can see the other account icons that are there, and I have a dropdown next to my primary account. Clicking on that allows me to choose a different account.

But since you don't know the password for the primary account, I would suggest the following options:

1. Log in to the Google account on the computer and reset the password. There you can click on *helpful links* like "forgot password". Once you reset the password you can change the password on the device and then the account will be verified.
2. Remove the account completely from the device. If the account isn't used for email and such, which since the phone is not logged in to the account, I would guess this is the case. Go into *Settings => Accounts* and remove the account that you do not know the password for.

Comment: 1. my dad does not know what he had put as recovery questions so he can't recover it  2. he can't delete the account without using a full reset reset

Comment: Then switching users is really your only other option. Or reset the device. Resetting the device won't affect any data on the sdcard. And since it's not logged in to the primary account, there isn't anything sync'd to that account, like contacts. It may take a little bit to set the device back up, but in the long run, it is the best option. Just make sure you export contacts and such, to be safe. Then you can import them to the new account so they stay in sync as well, in the future.